# Store elements in a vector Fortran

Tags: vector, fortran, fortran90

I have a very simple do loop in which I want to save (to store) the elements of a vector that is computed in the cycle to another one, such as I can recall the elements of this second vector outside the loop. 
My naively test is as follow:

program test

```
implicit none
integer :: num,i
real*8, DIMENSION(3, 1) :: pos
real*8, dimension(:),allocatable :: x(:)
real*8 :: step,delta


pos = 0.0 ! clear the vector all components are equal to zero
pos(1,1)=1. ! only first elements of the vector 'pos' of object 1 is diff. from zero 

num=1000
delta = 1.
step = 0.

allocate(x(num)) ! allocate a vector with dimension equal to num
x=0.
do while ( step < num )
           pos(1,1) = pos(1,1) + 0.5d0 ! move the objects                      
           x=pos(1,1)  ! store the elements of vector 'pos' in vector 'x'
           step = step + delta 
end do

print*, x(120) ! print the 120th elements of the vector x

end program test
```

I think the problem is on how i pass the elements from 'pos' to 'x' vector.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement

```
allocate(x(num)) ! allocate a vector with dimension equal to num
```

makes `x` a vector with `num` (i.e. `1000`) elements.  The next statement

```
x=0.
```

sets every element of `x` to `0.0`.  So far so good.  Then the code enters the loop where this statement

```
x=pos(1,1)  ! store the elements of vector 'pos' in vector 'x'
```

repeatedly sets every element of `x` to the latest value of `pos(1,1)`.  That's probably not what you want to do.  I think the easiest fix would be to rewrite the loop like this

```
do step = 1,1000
   pos(1,1) = pos(1,1) + 0.5d0 ! move the objects                      
   x(step) = pos(1,1)  ! store the elements of vector 'pos' in vector 'x'
end do
```

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, it looks as if you are trying to populate `x` with the terms in the arithmetic series `1 + n*0.5, n = [0,999]`.  A neater way to do that might be to modify what you have so that `x` is indexed from `0`, perhaps

```
allocate(x(0:num-1))
```

and then simply use a loop such as

```
do step = 1,999
   x(step) = x(step-1)+0.5
end do
```

I'm not sure why you involve `pos` in setting the values of `x` at all.

Comment: MANY THANKS !!!
I had a much more complex program that compute 'pos' with a long function and I like to store in x the results to re-use them outside the loop, in another loop in another part of the program. Here I post only a test program that mimic my more complex one.